# How to align two side-by-side align* equations at the top

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

How do I get it so these equation systems are top aligned? Here's the code:

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \bullet \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj & = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} \\
        & = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} - \binom nn \\
        & = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} - 1 \\
        & = (1 + 1)^n - 1 \\
        & = 2^n - 1    
    \end{aligned}
&\hspace{3cm}
    \begin{aligned}
    \bullet \sum_{j=0}^{n} 2^{j+1} \binom nj & = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{n} 2^j \binom nj \\
        & = 2(3)^n    
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

But it looks like this (I want them to be top aligned, side-by-side, with adequate spacing between them):
[image: LaTeX broken code]

Comment: `\begin{aligned}[t]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

```
\begin{aligned}[t]
\bullet \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj & = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} \\
    & = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} - \binom nn \\
    & = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} - 1 \\
    & = (1 + 1)^n - 1 \\
    & = 2^n - 1 
\end{aligned}
\hspace{3cm}
\begin{aligned}[t]
\bullet \sum_{j=0}^{n} 2^{j+1} \binom nj & = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{n} 2^j \binom nj \\
    & = 2(3)^n  
\end{aligned}
```

\end{equation*}

Comment: Such a simple and useful way to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also have more than one `&` per line.  Every even `&` is assumed to separate equations.  Equations will be evenly spaced across `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \bullet \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj & = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} &
    \bullet \sum_{j=0}^{n} 2^{j+1} \binom nj & = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{n} 2^j \binom nj \\
        & = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} - \binom nn &
        & = 2(3)^n \\
        & = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj 1^j 1^{n-j} - 1 \\
        & = (1 + 1)^n - 1 \\
        & = 2^n - 1 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Awesome I didn't know about that! I really just wanted them to be top aligned, I wasn't too concerned about whether the = signs themselves lined up, but definitely good for future reference